# unable to create autoincrementing primary key with flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want my model's primary key to be an autoincrementing integer. Here is how my model looks like

```
class Region(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('regions.id'))
    parent = db.relationship('Region', remote_side=id, primaryjoin=('Region.parent_id==Region.id'), backref='sub-regions')
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=db.func.now())
    deleted_at = db.Column(db.DateTime)
```

The above code creates my table but does not make `id` autoincrementing. So if in my insert query I miss the `id` field it gives me this error

> ERROR:  null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint

So I changed the `id` declaration to look like this

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence('seq_reg_id', start=1, increment=1),
               primary_key=True)
```

Still the same error. What is wrong with the code above?

Comment: can you post the code you use to create a region object?

Comment: i was trying to do a plain sql insert like `INSERT INTO regions(name, ) ...`

Comment: Your original code should work. Are you sure you are actually creating the table using SQLAlchemy. Are you sure you are looking at the right database? Try [configuring logging](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/core/engines.html#dbengine-logging) in SQLAlchemy and see what SQL is output when you use SQLAlchemy to create the table.

Comment: Very nice. Your code was my solution. I've been looking how to use Oracle's Sequences till your post. Thanks!

Comment: still same error

Answer (score 78):

Nothing is wrong with the above code.  In fact, you don't even need `autoincrement=True` or `db.Sequence('seq_reg_id', start=1, increment=1),` as SQLAlchemy will automatically set the first `Integer` PK column that's not marked as a FK as `autoincrement=True`.

Here, I've put together a working setup based on yours.  SQLAlechemy's ORM will take care of generating id's and populating objects with them *if you use the Declarative Base based class* that you've defined to create instances of your object.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://user:password@localhost/testdb'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Region(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'regions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100))

db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

region = Region(name='Over Yonder Thar')
app.logger.info(region.id) # currently None, before persistence

db.session.add(region)
db.session.commit()
app.logger.info(region.id) # gets assigned an id of 1 after being persisted

region2 = Region(name='Yet Another Up Yar')
db.session.add(region2)
db.session.commit()
app.logger.info(region2.id) # and 2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port=9001)
```

Comment: I am in a similar kind of a situation. Say there are 4 records in the table as of now, from id 1 to 4. When I do a `db.session.query(Table_name).delete()
db.session.commit()` and then if I do a `db.session.add()` again to add new records, the next record gets an id of 5. Since my table is now empty, I want my new records to now get an id starting from 1 again. How can I do this ?

Comment: Sort of a side comment that I was trying to figure out a different-but-related question of how to populate my database based on model.py, and found `db.drop_all()` and `db.create_all()` to be super helpful.  Thanks.

Comment: This also applies to Oracle databases, where you have to install/setup a sequence to handle the AUTOINCREMENT primary key handling.

Comment: this is not working `  null value in column "module_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains`

Comment: @qre0ct this is actually pointless in regard to relational databases, since you wont be able to add/delete multiple rows concurrently. Every time you change ID, your database engine will have to check if everything is all right with your indices. ID column **should not be meaningful**. There are some exceptions to the rule, of course. If you're worried you'll run out of IDs, just assign `BigInt` and forget it forever.

Answer (score 20):

So I landed here with an issue that my SQLite table wasn't auto-incrementing the primary key. I have a slightly complex use case where I want to use postgres in production but sqlite for testing to make life a bit easier when continuously deploying.

It turns out SQLite doesn't like columns defined as BigIntegers, and for incrementing to work they should be set as Integers.  Remarkably SQLAlchemy can handle this scenario as follows using the with_variant function.  Thought this may be useful for someone:

```
id = db.Column(db.BigInteger().with_variant(db.Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)
```

Further details here https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html

Comment: I'm landing here with the same issue (prod=postgresql, testing=sqlite) yet all my primary keys are already Integers. A bit absurd but this still fixed it:



`id = db.Column(db.Integer().with_variant(Integer, "sqlite"), primary_key=True)`

Comment: this is the best answer for my problem(postgresql->production, sqlite->test). thank you

Answer (score 14):

I think you do not need the autoincrement once you set ,

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True , autoincrement=True)
```

I think that it should be ,

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer , primary_key=True)
```

it will give you the uniqueness your looking for .

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue declaring **Composite Keys** on a model class.

If you are wanting an auto-incrementing id field for a composite key (ie. more than 1 `db.Column(..)` definition with `primary_key=True`, then adding `autoincrement=True` fixed the issue for me.

```py
class S3Object(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 's3_object'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)

    # composite keys
    bucket_name = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
    key = db.Column(db.String(), primary_key=True)
```

So the statements above about not requiring `autoincrement=True` should be :

> you don't even need `autoincrement=True`, as SQLAlchemy will automatically set the first
> Integer PK column that's not marked as a FK as `autoincrement=True` *unless you are defining a composite key with more than one `primary_key=True`*

Answer (score 6):

Your id auto increments by default even without setting the autoincrement=True flag.

So there's nothing wrong with using

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
```

The error you're getting is as a result of attempting to populate the table with an id attribute. Your insert query shouldn't at any point contain an id attribute otherwise you'll get that error.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, even after adding `autoincrement=True`.

The problem was I already had the migration created. So I downgraded to the previous migration, deleted the migration, created the migration again and upgraded.

Then the error was gone.

Hope it helps someone stuck on this.

Wrapping off: Add `autoincrement=True`, and ensure your migration is updated and applied.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add "autoincrement" flag in column definition, moreover add "__table__args" attribute just after __table__name.
Something like this:

> ```
>     __tablename__ = 'table-name'
>     __table_args__ = {'sqlite_autoincrement': True} -> This adds autoincrement to your primary key.
> ```

Try it, I hope this work for you ;) !

Answer (score -1):

In my case, I just added the id as external parameter, without relying on sqlalchemy

Answer (score -1):

Try this code out, it worked for me.

Within the `__init__` function don't specify the id, so when you create a new "User" object SQLAlchemy will automatically generate an id number for you uniquely.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///users.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLAlCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    _id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True, autoincrement = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique = True, nullable = False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique = True, nullable = False)

def __init__(self, username, email):
    self.username = username
    self.email = email
```

This line of code will create our intended table inside our database.

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()


admin = User(username = 'another admin', email='another_admin@mail.com')
guest = User(username = 'another guest', email='another_guest@mail.com')
```

This code below will push our data into our table.

```
with app.app_context():
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.add(guest)
    db.session.commit()
```

Comment: SQLAlchemy provides a default `__init__` function already, there is no need to add one.