# Primary id sequence not incrementing

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sequence, auto-increment

I have a table set up like this:

```
USERS_TABLE = \
        Table("users", META_DATA,
              Column("id", Integer, Sequence("user_id_seq"), primary_key=True),
              Column("first_name", String(255)),
              Column("last_name", String(255))
             )
```

I am able to insert a **single row** like this:

```
INS_EXPRESSION = insert(USERS_TABLE)
SEQ = Sequence('user_id_seq')
INS_EXPRESSION.values(first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar")
```

But, if I try a **second insert**, I get this error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (psycopg2.IntegrityError) null value in column "id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (null, null, null).
 [SQL: 'INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES']
```

How do I make the `user_id_seq` sequence **auto-increment**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is that current version of [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object definition gives us next [`CREATE TABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) statement

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    first_name VARCHAR(255), 
    last_name VARCHAR(255), 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

while it probably should be

1. this

   ```
   CREATE TABLE users (
       id INTEGER DEFAULT nextval('user_id_seq') NOT NULL, 
       first_name VARCHAR(255), 
       last_name VARCHAR(255), 
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
   )
   ```
2. or simply this

   ```
   CREATE TABLE users (
       id SERIAL NOT NULL, 
       first_name VARCHAR(255), 
       last_name VARCHAR(255), 
       PRIMARY KEY (id)
   )
   ```

So for each statement solutions are:

1. Following [this recipe](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#associating-a-sequence-as-the-server-side-default) we can set `server_default` to sequence's `nextval` like

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import (MetaData, Table, Column,
                           Integer, String, Sequence,
                           create_engine,
                           insert)


   db_uri = 'postgresql://username:password@hostname:5432/database'
   engine = create_engine(db_uri)
   META_DATA = MetaData(bind=engine)
   user_id_seq = Sequence("user_id_seq", metadata=META_DATA)
   USERS_TABLE = Table("users", META_DATA,
                       Column("id", Integer, user_id_seq,
                              server_default=user_id_seq.next_value(),
                              primary_key=True),
                       Column("first_name", String(255)),
                       Column("last_name", String(255)))
   USERS_TABLE.create(checkfirst=True)
   INS_EXPRESSION = insert(USERS_TABLE).values(first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar")
   engine.execute(INS_EXPRESSION)
   engine.execute('INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES')
   ```
2. If using [`Sequence`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence) is not crucial than we can remove it and just set [`autoincrement`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) flag to `True` (it will also work with `Sequence` removed without setting flag [because](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20861531/5997596)

   > ... SQLAlchemy will automatically set the first Integer PK column that's not marked as a FK as `autoincrement=True`...

   but it will be better with it since it is more [explicit](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#the-zen-of-python)):

   ```
   from sqlalchemy import MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, create_engine, insert

   db_uri = 'postgresql://username:password@hostname:5432/database'
   engine = create_engine(db_uri)
   META_DATA = MetaData(bind=engine)

   USERS_TABLE = Table("users", META_DATA,
                       Column("id", Integer,
                              autoincrement=True,
                              primary_key=True),
                       Column("first_name", String(255)),
                       Column("last_name", String(255)))
   USERS_TABLE.create(checkfirst=True)

   INS_EXPRESSION = insert(USERS_TABLE).values(first_name="Foo", last_name="Bar")
   engine.execute(INS_EXPRESSION)
   engine.execute('INSERT INTO users DEFAULT VALUES')
   ```

I will prefer the second one since using `Sequence` looks like [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

---

#### P. S.

Why are you using UPPER_CASE'd names by the way? These objects doesn't look like [constants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) to me since you can [mutate](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-immutable) them freely ([PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants))