# how to get the auto increment id in flask-sqlalchemy orm mode

Tags: python, flask, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I use flask sqlalchemy orm added a record, but how can I get the id field?

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.sql.schema import Column
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Table(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(String(2000))

person = Table()
person.name = 'peter'

db.session.add(person)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848300/unable-to-create-autoincrementing-primary-key-with-flask-sqlalchemy

Answer (score -1):

Autocommit should be set on as a default for this transaction.

ref http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execution_options.params.autocommit

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/connections.html#understanding-autocommit

Assuming auto commit is on, you'll have to query your table and select the id field.

```
result = session.query(person).filter_by(name='peter').first()

print result.id
```